# derive additional column based on existing column

Tags: r

```
                       year
  ID                   2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012
  Altstadt/Nord        17821 17947 17764 17301 17211 17337 17421 17330
  Altstadt/Süd         26706 26778 26693 26218 26657 26443 26677 26722
  Bayenthal             8117  8388  8411  8455  8479  8834  8981  8911
  Bickendorf           16350 16303 16383 16321 16351 16429 16692 16813
```

I have created this table using: `xtabs(Einwohneranzahl~raum+jahr,subsetHH)`.

Now i want it as a subset in order to derive an addition column (average on all years).

Comment: @DavideBrex                                                                                                                                       
structure(c(17821, 26706, 8117, 16350, 14834, 6023, 10610, 10161,...
.Dim = c(86L, 8L), .Dimnames = list(
    raum = c("Altstadt/Nord", "Altstadt/Süd", "Bayenthal", "Bickendorf",...
"table"), call = xtabs(formula = Einwohneranzahl ~ raum + jahr, 
    data = subsetHH))

Comment: @rookiestudent069 Hi! You can update the question with the code that you posted in the comment above.

Comment: This code is irreproducible: ` structure(c(17821, 26706, 8117, 16350, 14834, 6023, 10610, 10161,... .Dim = c(86L, 8L), .Dimnames = list( raum = c("Altstadt/Nord", "Altstadt/Süd", "Bayenthal", "Bickendorf",... "table"), call = xtabs(formula = Einwohneranzahl ~ raum + jahr, data = subsetHH))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowMeans` to add a *mean over all years* like:

```
x$Mean <- rowMeans(x[-1])
x
#             ID X2005 X2006 X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010 X2011 X2012     Mean
#1 Altstadt/Nord 17821 17947 17764 17301 17211 17337 17421 17330 17516.50
#2  Altstadt/Süd 26706 26778 26693 26218 26657 26443 26677 26722 26611.75
#3     Bayenthal  8117  8388  8411  8455  8479  8834  8981  8911  8572.00
#4    Bickendorf 16350 16303 16383 16321 16351 16429 16692 16813 16455.25
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=" ID                   2005  2006  2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012
  Altstadt/Nord        17821 17947 17764 17301 17211 17337 17421 17330
  Altstadt/Süd         26706 26778 26693 26218 26657 26443 26677 26722
  Bayenthal             8117  8388  8411  8455  8479  8834  8981  8911
  Bickendorf           16350 16303 16383 16321 16351 16429 16692 16813")
```

Answer (score 0):

The rowSums() function can do this. It's a bit easier if you turn it into a data frame first.

```
library(dplyr)
# Make Cross tab and turn into data frame
cross_tab <- as.data.frame(xtabs(Einwohneranzahl~raum+jahr,subsetHH))

# Add a column that is the sum of each row
mutate(cross_tab, all_years = rowSums(cross_tab))
```

Comment: Isn't he asking for the average?

Answer (score 0):

If speed of execution is not an issue (`rowSums`, `rowMeans` are faster), you can also use `apply` (using @GKi's data) as well as `sum`(if you want to add up the values):

```
x$new <- apply(x[-1], 1, sum)
```

Result:

```
x
             ID X2005 X2006 X2007 X2008 X2009 X2010 X2011 X2012    new
1 Altstadt/Nord 17821 17947 17764 17301 17211 17337 17421 17330 140132
2  Altstadt/Süd 26706 26778 26693 26218 26657 26443 26677 26722 212894
3     Bayenthal  8117  8388  8411  8455  8479  8834  8981  8911  68576
4    Bickendorf 16350 16303 16383 16321 16351 16429 16692 16813 131642
```

If it is the average you want to compute replace `sum` by `mean`.